# How to keep the scrollbar on previous position?

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I have a div and after inserting dynamic data - its scrollbar always go to the top position (value 0).

```
$(document).on('click', '.title', function(){
    var scroll = $('#div').scrollTop();
    console.log(scroll); // for example - 120
    $.post('common.php', {vars}, function(data) {
        $('#div').html(data), function(){$('#div').scrollTop(scroll)};
        var scroll = $('#div').scrollTop();
        console.log(scroll);  // result 0 - expected 120
    });
});
```

How to keep the scrollbar on previous position?

Comment: Can you provide complete code or sample code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @KamalaHB, complete code is there. Example code is not possible because `data` is comming from a remote position.

Comment: Try adding this line where you want to focus.  document.getElementById('div').focus(); See if it works!

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML and CSS. The fact the data is coming from a remote source isn't a problem; you could provide an example of the HTML being returned in the AJAX request.

Comment: @KamalaHB, tried just now, the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use cookies.

They are quite easy to use with native JS (source [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) ) :

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

And now you can have a function to keep your position-cookie Up-to-date (like every 2 seconds)

```
setInterval(function() { setCookie('Ypos', scroll, 2); }, 2000);
```

I haven't tested any of this, but it seems a nice way to make what you want

(By the way, this idea came from my GoogleApp "Great Suspender", that leaves a few "gsScrollPos" in my cookies)